# How to configure different Jest testEnvironment for React Components and Backend API routes in NextJs?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, jestjs

NextJS supports Jest (with little configuration) along with React Testing library for testing frontend. We can also use Jest to test our backend code.

I am using a library in my API routes which relies on internal nodejs APIs. For them to work in the test environment, I need to set the `jestConfig.testEnvironment` to `node`.

For testing frontend React components, I need to set the `jestConfig.testEnvironment` to `jest-environment-jsdom`.

I know I can mock the backend library, but I want to emulate real environment without having to mock any library implementation.

One way I could think of was to use different file extensions for frontend (`filename.frontend.test.ts`) and backend (`filename.backend.test.ts`) tests. Then, I could create 2 different jest config files and specify the file extensions using the `jestConfig.testMatch` property in the respective config file. And I could then do the following in the npm scripts:

```json
{
  "scripts": {
    "test:frontend": "jest --config jest.config.frontend.ts",
    "test:backend": "jest --config jest.config.backend.ts",
    "test": "npm-run-all test:*"
  }
}
```

I was wondering if there is a better way to do this?

I am using the following library versions:

- next: 13+
- jest: 29+
- @testing-library/react: 13+

Answer (score 1):

You may want to look into the `projects` field of the jest config.

https://jestjs.io/docs/configuration#projects-arraystring--projectconfig

Here's an example of running node and react tests in the same repo:

https://blog.jmtalarn.com/running-node-js-react-tests-same-project/

You can also add a doc-block at the top of tests to set the environment for that specific test:

```js
/**
 * @jest-environment jsdom
 */
```

Comment: Yea, but I will have to set this up in all those files which is annoying. Also, globalSetup and globalTeardown files will be tied to the environment in `jest.config.ts`.